# flutter web forms work in mac browsers (firefox, chrome) but not in windows or ios browsers (firefox, chrome, safari)

Tags: windows, forms, flutter, google-chrome, web

So I'm new to flutter and maybe I've completely borked forms, but I'm getting this weird behavior where the form works just fine in browsers under Mac OS but do not work at all in browsers on Windows or iOS. By work, I mean being able to use a button to submit data.

It appears to be a problem with a funky layout: the controls are covering each other up, but I'm not sure why this is happening on windows and iOS but not on macOS. It is consistent across browsers: it seems to work fine in every browser on mac, and not to work in any browser on iOS or Windows.

Flutter 1.25.0-8.1.pre • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 8f89f6505b (2 weeks ago) • 2020-12-15 15:07:52 -0800
Engine • revision 92ae191c17
Tools • Dart 2.12.0 (build 2.12.0-133.2.beta)

**WORKS:** (can enter data in fields, click submit, and data shows up below)
macOS Catalina Version 10.15.7
Firefox: 84.0.1, Chrome: 87.0.4280.88 (Official Build) (x86_64),
Safari: 14.0.1 (15610.2.11.51.10, 15610)

**NOT WORKING** (selecting fields is flakey, button not pressable, can't submit data)
Windows 10 Pro 20H2, Firefox 84.6.1, Edge
iOS 14.2 Safari, Firefox, Chrome (latest versions)

I'm serving the flutter web build with nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu).

**form_widget.dart:**

```
import 'package:field_test/helpers/size_helpers.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FormWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _FormWidgetState();

}

class _FormWidgetState extends State<FormWidget> {
  String _keywords, _keywords_display = "";
  String _type, _type_display = "";
  String _state, _state_display = "";

  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  Widget _buildKeywordsField() {
    return TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Keywords'),
        onSaved: (String value) {
          _keywords = value;
          print(_keywords + "saved");
        }
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTypeField() {
    return TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Type'),
        onSaved: (String value) {
          _type = value;
          print(_type + "saved");
        }
    );
  }

  Widget _buildStateField() {
    return TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'State'),
        onSaved: (String value) {
          _state = value;
          print(_state + "saved");
        }
    );
  }

  void _update() {
    print("update called");
    setState(() {
      _keywords_display = _keywords;
      _type_display = _type;
      _state_display = _state;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Form Widget",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
          )
        )
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget> [
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(24),
                child: Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget> [
                      _buildKeywordsField(),
                      _buildTypeField(),
                      _buildStateField(),
                      SizedBox(height: 15),
                      RaisedButton(
                        child: Text(
                          'Search',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () => {
                          _formKey.currentState.save(),
                          _update(),
                        }
                      )
                    ]
                  )
                )
              )
            ),
            Container(
              width: displayWidth(context) * .95,
              height: displayHeight(context) * .75,
              child:
                Builder(
                  builder: (_) {
                    return ListView.separated(
                      separatorBuilder: (_, __) =>
                      Divider(height: 1, color: Colors.orange),
                      itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                        return ListTile(
                          isThreeLine: true,
                          title: Text(
                            "Keywords: " + _keywords_display,
                            style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                          ),
                          subtitle: Text(
                              "Type: " + _type_display + "\nState: " + _state_display,
                          maxLines: 2,
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      itemCount: 1,
                    );

                  }),
            )]
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

**size_helpers.dart:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Size displaySize(BuildContext context) {
  return MediaQuery.of(context).size;
}

double displayHeight(BuildContext context) {
  return displaySize(context).height;
}

double displayWidth(BuildContext context) {
  return displaySize(context).width;
}
```

**main.dart:**

```
import 'package:field_test/widgets/form_widget.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.orange,
      ),
      home: FormWidget(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I was over-complicating the form. The Expanded() in the form part seemed to be confusing the browser. The following code works on all platforms AFAICT:

```
body: Center(
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(24),
                      child: 
                      Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        _buildKeywordsField(),
                        _buildTypeField(),
                        _buildStateField(),
                        SizedBox(height: 15),
                        RaisedButton(
                            child: Text(
                              'Search',
                              style:
                                  TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                            ),
                            onPressed: () => {
                                  _formKey.currentState.save(),
                                  _update(),
                                })
                      ])
                      ),
,
                      ),
```